# CI: Automated Build Studio vs. Hudson vs. Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, automated-deploy, bamboo

What would be the best tool to use that can support cross platforms, remote builds and deployment for windows, linux and macosx and cost effective?
Right now were using Groovy(grails), Java, and .NET

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are pretty vague, so expect vague answers. Hudson sounds like it would be a reasonable fit (cross platform, remote builds, etc), but your best bet is to actually [try it](http://hudson-ci.org/)! Hudson has a good community and plenty of activity. Read the [wiki](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson), search the [mailing lists](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Mailing%20List) and ask questions when you get stuck.

The "cost effective" requirement is nearly impossible for an outsider to measure because we have no idea what tradeoffs you're willing to make with build vs buy, nor do we know how valuable your time is compared to your money.

Wikipedia's [Comparison of Continuous Integration software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Continuous_Integration_Software) may be helpful if you want an overview of what else is out there.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave. Well right now were currently building apps for iphone, but from the past we use .net to build other apps. After doing some research, it seems to have boiled down between bamboo and hudson since ABS only supports .NET, Java and windows languages. What are your comments between Bamboo vs Hudson? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My company uses Bamboo.  I can recommend it as a decent product.  I have not used Hudson extensively enough to say that it's better, although my limited experience with it says that it is at least as good.

The fact Hudson is free has to be one plus for it.

Try them both out, and see which you like better.  Bamboo has a 30 day free trial. [link](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/BambooDownloadCenter.jspa)

One thing about Bamboo that has been a negative is that we have a huge number of plans, and plan maintenance and creation is all Web GUI driven.  There is very little room to automate plan creation, from my experience.  I believe Hudson "plans" can be created almost on the fly via command line arguments.